# vba update cell with data validation?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have 2 worksheets, Product Groups and Database:

My sheet, Product Groups has a layout like below:

```
A4
A5      {Button}
A6
A7
A8
```

A user can add values to column A4 onwards. Meaning this list could extend to A4- A8 or A4 to A100.

I have created a button that allows the user to run a macro after they have updated the values in column A.

This macro should insert the values from A4 to Last used row into my data validation in Cell T7 on my database sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub button()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups").Range("A4" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim range1 As Range, rng As Range
'change Sheet1 to suit
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups")


Set rng = ws.Range("T7")
Set range1 = ws2.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

With rng.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & range1.Address
End With


End Sub
```

For some reason i get an error on this line:

```
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups").Range("A4" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Application undefined or object undefined error.

Please can someone show me where this is going wrong? THanks

Comment: Try `lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups").Range("A4" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` ...(You may not need the second `ThisWorkbook.` but you will need the worksheet.)

Comment: nearly that; it's `LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups").Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups").Rows.count).End(xlUp).row`

Comment: @user3598756 Beat me to it. You can't define row 4 using `Range("A4")` and then try to redefine the row. You would just use the Column A portion of `Range` and define the row portion using the `.Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution has been given in comments

I use the answer that shows it again along with a possible refactoring of your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub button()
    Dim range1 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Groups")
        Set range1 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("T7").Validation
        .Delete 'delete previous validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='Product Groups!" & range1.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Princess.Bell, you may also find the time to give feedbacks to answers to previous questions of yours!